# Bootstrap code doesn't copy the kernel properly

Tags: assembly, operating-system, x86-16, bootloader, bios

The bootloader doesn't copy the memory from disk to address 0x10000. Actually, the first few sectors are copied well, but at a certain point, it just stops copying and jumps to the kernel.

Here's my code:

```
[ORG 0x00]
[BITS 16]           

SECTION .text       

jmp 0x07C0:START    

TOTALSECTORCOUNT: dw 0x200

KERNEL32SECTORCOUNT: dw 0x05

START:
    (...)                

RESETDISK:                          

    mov ax, 0
    mov dl, 0
    int 0x13

    jc HANDLEDISKERROR


    mov si, 0x1000                  
    mov es, si                      
    mov bx, 0x0000                  

    mov di, word [ TOTALSECTORCOUNT ] 

READDATA:               
    cmp di, 0           
    je READEND          
    sub di, 0x1

    mov ah, 0x02                    
    mov al, 0x1                     
    mov ch, byte [ TRACKNUMBER ]    
    mov cl, byte [ SECTORNUMBER ]   
    mov dh, byte [ HEADNUMBER ]     
    mov dl, 0x00                    
    int 0x13                        
    jc HANDLEDISKERROR              

    add si, 0x0020      
    mov es, si          



    mov al, byte [ SECTORNUMBER ]   
    add al, 0x01                    
    mov byte [ SECTORNUMBER ], al   
    cmp al, 19                      
    jl READDATA                     


    xor byte [ HEADNUMBER ], 0x01   
    mov byte [ SECTORNUMBER ], 0x01 


    cmp byte [ HEADNUMBER ], 0x00   
    jne READDATA                    


    add byte [ TRACKNUMBER ] , 0x01 
    jmp READDATA                    
READEND:
    push LOADINGCOMPLETEMESSAGE     
    push 2                         
    push 0                        
    call PRINTMESSAGE               
    add sp, 6                   

    jmp 0x1000:0x0000


HANDLEDISKERROR:
    push DISKERRORMESSAGE   
    push 2                
    push 0               
    call PRINTMESSAGE       
    add sp, 6               

    jmp $                   

    (...)


SECTORNUMBER:       db  0x02    
HEADNUMBER:         db  0x00    
TRACKNUMBER:        db  0x00    



times 510 - ( $ - $$ )  db  0x00    


db 0x55             
db 0xAA
```

This code just copied 11 sectors... Which the original was 26 sectors though.

Also, it runs unstably in bochs, but qemu just reboots the virtual machine.

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

> This code just copied 11 sectors... Which the original was **26** sectors though.

Why then do you try to load **512** sectors? (`TOTALSECTORCOUNT: dw 0x200`)

---

Did you setup the `DS` segment register to 0x07C0 ?

You should use the drive number from the `DL` register that you received from BIOS on entry, instead of the hard coded `mov dl, 0x00`.

Are you sure of the disk's geometry? Is it 18 sectors and 2 heads? Better use BIOS function `int 13h, ah=08h` to find out!

> ```
> START:
> (...)
> ```

For better help, please fill in the actual code.

Comment: mov ax, 0x07C0  /
    mov ds, ax      /
    mov ax, 0xB800 /
    mov es, ax    /

    
    mov ax, 0x0000  /
    mov ss, ax      /
    mov sp, 0xFFFE / 
    mov bp, 0xFFFE  /

    mov si, 0  /
This is the START function. So, I think I set ds reg to 0x07C0, and I edited TOTALSECTORCOUNT to 0x1A, but it's still not working. I'll test the int 13h to my code soon!!

Comment: And how can I check the drive parameters with assembly code?

Comment: and then, why is it runs only in bochs? I mounted the image to fda both.